# How to integrate linkpager in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Iam new to yii2. How to integrate the Yii 2.0: yii2-widget-linkpager

Kindly give me a detailed and step by step instructions.

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this  [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-widget-linkpager/)

you have type this code in your terminal `composer require --prefer-dist liyunfang/yii2-widget-linkpager`